# How to rename a ZIP in Bamboo

Tags: shell, ant, zip, continuous-integration, bamboo

I have been handed a Bamboo build/job and have never worked with it before. There are 2 existing tasks, **Task A** and **Task B**.  Task A does stuff to a ZIP named `myapp.zip`, but Task B expects it to be named `widget.zip`. For reasons outside the context of this question, I cannot modify Tasks A or B.

So, I need a way to insert a task in between these 2 existing ones, and change the name of `myapp.zip` to `widget.zip`. Is there a way to do this using Ant or some shell commands? If so, since I'm brand new to Bamboo, can someone please give me detailed instructions on how to configure this "Rename" task?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the most elegant solution and it depends on your OS:

Create a new "Command" Task and define an executable to a rename tool of your os (like /bin/mv). Then use this executable with your zip file as a parameters:

> executable: mv
>
> parameters: path/myapp.zip path/widget.zip